# How to get nodes specifically related to two nodes and not others in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two types of labels User and Conversation
User have outgoing relation with Conversation

```
(u:User)-[:IS_PARTICIPANT]->(c:Conversation)
```

Multiple Users can be participant of the Conversation. 
Now what I am trying to query is for conversation that is specifically between two users only.

for ex.

```
MATCH (p1:User {name: 'Tom'})-[:IS_PARTICIPANT]->(c:Conversation)<-[:IS_PARTICIPANT]-(p2:User {name:"Jerry"})
return c
```

Above query does return conversation between two users Tom and Jerry but it will also return this conversation even if there is other user Tweety in that specific conversation. Is there a way in cypher we can specifically get conversation where only specific users are participant of and not others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the node, and find out how many others are connected to it:

```
MATCH   (p1:User {name: 'Tom'})
       -[:IS_PARTICIPANT]->(c:Conversation)<-[:IS_PARTICIPANT]
       -(p2:User {name:"Jerry"})
MATCH (c)<-[:IS_PARTICIPANT]-(u:User)
WITH c, 
     COUNT(u) AS countUser WHERE countUser = 2
return c
```

If nodes are more then two:

```
WITH ["Tom", "Jerry", "Tweety"] as names
MATCH (p:User)-[:IS_PARTICIPANT]->(c:Conversation) 
      WHERE p.name IN names
WITH distinct c, 
     names
MATCH (c)<-[:IS_PARTICIPANT]-(u:User) 
      WHERE u.name in names
WITH distinct c, 
     names, 
     count(distinct u) as countUser 
     WHERE countUser = size(names)
RETURN c
```

Comment: I found out we could also do 
WHERE SIZE((c)<-[:IS_PARTICIPANT]-(:User)) = 2

Comment: It will be interesting to solve the problem if the initial nodes are more than two.

Comment: How about this 
`MATCH(p:User) WHERE p.name IN ["Tom", "Jerry", "Tweety"]
MATCH(c:Conversation)<-[:IS_PARTICIPANT]-(p)
WHERE SIZE((c)<-[:IS_PARTICIPANT]-(:User)) = 3
RETURN c`

Comment: Close, but this query does not guarantee that the remaining nodes from the array are also connected to the `c: Conversation` node.

Comment: does not `MATCH(c:Conversation)<-[:IS_PARTICIPANT]-(p)` this part of the query check for that? I am still testing this though

Comment: Updated the answer: added an option for the number of nodes greater than two.

Comment: Thanks just tested it and seems to be working. Will test in details. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few tricks we can use here.

First, given an arbitrary-sized collections of names (where you know all the names correspond with :Users), [this knowledge base entry](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/performing-match-intersection/) can be helpful for determining when all of the given nodes have a relationship to the same node.

Second, if the :IS_PARTICIPANT relationship always only connects :User and :Conversation nodes, we can use `size(()-[:IS_PARTICIPANT]->(c))` to efficiently get the number of incoming :IS_PARTICIPANT relationships to a conversation without having to pay the cost of actually expanding those relationships.

```
WITH ["Tom", "Jerry", "Tweety"] as names // should be parameterized instead
WITH names, size(names) as requiredCount
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE u.name in names
WITH u, requiredCount
MATCH (u)-[:IS_PARTICIPANT]->(c:Conversation)
WITH requiredCount, c, count(u) as matches
WHERE requiredCount = matches and size(()-[:IS_PARTICIPANT]->(c)) = requiredCount
RETURN c
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Seems like I missed the KB entry for match intersection, Really useful stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something like this in mind?

```
MATCH (p1:User {name: 'Tom'})-[:IS_PARTICIPANT]->(c:Conversation)<-[:IS_PARTICIPANT]-(p2:User {name: 'Jerry'})
WHERE NOT (c:Conversation)<-[:IS_PARTICIPANT]-(:User {name: 'The Dog'})
RETURN c
```

Here, the User `The Dog` is not a participant of the conversation.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for reply but this might not be helpful if we have more users related to conversation.